# Regex.Split Not working properly?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following input:

```
void Main()
{
    string inputData = "37.7879\r\n-122.3874\r\n40.7805\r\n-111.9288\r\n36.0667\r\n-115.0927\r\n37.7879\r\n-122.3874";
    // string[] inputLines = Regex.Split(inputData, @"\r\n");
    string[] inputLines = Regex.Split(inputData, @"(\r)?\n");
    Console.WriteLine("The size of the list is: {0}", inputLines.Length);
    bool results = inputLines.All(IsValidNumber);

    foreach (string line in inputLines)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is: {1}", line, IsValidNumber(line));
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public bool IsValidNumber(string input)
{
    Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"^-?\d+\.\d+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return match.Success;
}
```

I am trying to a `Regex.Split` on `@"\r\n"`, if I use the commented line, then I get the expected results.  If I use the uncommented one, I do not get the results I expect.  I'm almost 100% positive that my regex is correct *if* the `"\r"` doesn't exist (which may or may not be the case).

I'm expecting 8 values from inputData that I'm trying to validate if they're all valid numbers.

Is there a possibility that my `"(\r)?"` isn't working correctly?  If so, what am I missing?

Comment: In other words, the parentheses are tripping you up. The correct way to write it is `@"(?:\r)?\n"`, with non-capturing parentheses. Or, as p.s.w.g is saying, `\r` is a single character, so you don't even need grouping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your pattern contains a capturing group `Regex.Split` will capture the group as it's splitting the contents. This will give you 15 items instead of just 8.

If you're only trying to make a single character or character class optional, you don't need a group. Try getting rid of the group around `\r`:

```
string[] inputLines = Regex.Split(inputData, @"\r?\n");
```

Alternatively, yes, you can make it a non-capturing group:

```
string[] inputLines = Regex.Split(inputData, @"(?:\r)?\n");
```

Comment: I am aware of the capture variables and I completely forgot that \r is one character.  I thought it was two characters which is I'm using the parenthesis.

Comment: @coson Okay, I should clarify. `@"\r"` is actually two characters *as a string*, however, when it appears in a regular expression, it *represents* a single character to match.